# What does 'off' mean in 'to offset'?

Tags: etymology

> [offset (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=offset&searchmode=none) =
>       1550s, "act of setting off" (on a journey, etc.), from [***off***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=off&allowed_in_frame=0) + [set](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=set&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.).
>    Meaning "something **'set OFF' against** something else, a counterbalance" is from 1769; the verb in this sense is from 1792.

Abbreviate 'something' to 'sth'. 1. What does the prefix ***off*** signify?

2. What imagery can explain ***off*** ? Envisage an unbalanced scale like:

[image]

Then balancing demands decreasing Work or increasing Life: but how can either be sensed as ***off***?

3. Isn't  ***off*** redundant? Doesn't 'to set sth (something) against sth else'
   = 'to set sth ***off***  against sth else' ?

Comment: Hello again—I see you have changed your username.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the effect of "**off**" in "offset" is largely serving the role of a *preposition*: it describes a spatial relationship. The relationship is that you are arranging two items or concepts so that they balance each other out.

The spatial relationship implied by *offset* is frequently figurative, not literal. For instance, when you *offset* a debt by paying it back, you're usually not literally putting money on a scale with your debt on one side and your payments on another. But conceptually, that's what you're doing -- canceling them out so that they balance, or at least diminishing the effect of the first object.

> What does the prefix off mean here?

One note: Generally an English speaker would not necessarily think of "off" in "offset" as a prefix, but rather as just a syllable that forms a part of the word.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Can you please explain more about the imagery or metaphor behind 'off'? If I imagine offsetting X against Y as balancing X and Y both on a scale, then where does the preposition 'off' enter?